# Can this for-loop calculation of np.meshgrid be vectorized?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, for-loop, vectorization

I have a section inside my code, where I, via a `for` loop, allocate the results from `np.meshgrid` applied on a slice of `my_array` into a place holder `res_array` as follows:

```
p = 360; q = 50; r = 50
my_array   =  np.random.rand(p, q, 2)
res_array  = np.zeros((p,q,r), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(p):
   x, x_ = np.meshgrid(my_array[i,:,0], my_array[i,:,0])
   res_array[i] = (x_-x)
```

There are a couple of similar operations more inside my code and I have to run my code several thousands of time. Therefore speed becomes an issue. I was thinking that I can save some time here if I can do without a `for` loop, however I am unable to do it myself.

How do this without the for loop?

EDIT HISTORY:

1. Note that `my_array[i,:,1]` is not use in the snipet shown above. I similarly, use `my_array[i,:,1]` in another code block (not shown here, but similar loop). This is what I mean by "There are a couple of similar operations more inside my code ..."

Comment: `my_array[i,:,1]` is not used. Is it normal? Did you mean something like `np.meshgrid(my_array[i,:,0], my_array[i,:,1])`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that our @Jerome. Similarly,  I use ```my_array[i,:,1]``` in another code block. This is what I meant by "There are a couple of similar operations more inside my code ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite np.meshgrid as faster lower-level numpy operations:

```py
p = 360; q = 50; r = 50
my_array   =  np.random.rand(p, q, 2)
res_array  = np.zeros((p,q,r), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(p):
    x = my_array[None,i,:,0].repeat(q, axis=0).reshape(q, q)
    y = my_array[None,i,:,0].repeat(q, axis=1).reshape(q, q)
    res_array[i] = y - x
```

This code is 2 times faster on my machine.
**Numba's `@njit`** can be used to speed-up the above code (again 3 times faster), but a much more efficient implementation is possible using it. Here it is:

```py
@njit(parallel=True)
def fasterImpl(my_array, p, q, r):
    res_array = np.zeros((p, q, r))
    for i in prange(p):
        for j in range(q):
            for k in range(r):
                res_array[i,j,k] = my_array[i,j,0] - my_array[i,k,0]
    return res_array

p = 360; q = 50; r = 50
my_array   = np.random.rand(p, q, 2)
res_array  = fasterImpl(my_array, p, q, r)
```

This final implementation is 29 times faster than the original one on my machine!

Comment: 1/2 @Jerome. Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me. Your first implementation is already giving me a speed benefit of ~5 seconds over a benchmark case of 500 function runs. This helps me.

Comment: 2/2 However, when I tried the ```Numba``` implementation, it gave me an error "Unknown attribute 'repeat' of type array".  Pardon, me but I have not used ```Numba``` before. I know you have helped me in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203578/fast-alternative-to-conditionally-set-an-array-elements?noredirect=1#comment111764924_63203578) question today. There, although I could get the code running, but not with any noticeable speed gains. I suspect if I am using it right. Right now, I have put the ```Numba``` based function outside the _calculator_ function, and then calling it.

Comment: @your_boy_gorja I edited the code regarding your edit so the code can be easily edited. The new numba implementation does not use `repeat` anymore (the issue was probably related to the version of numba). The new numba code is even faster. Regarding the timing of the numba version, note that the first run is generally slow as numba have to compile it. You should use it many times so it can be useful (you can also call the function in the beginning of your program to compile it outside of any hot paths). Moreover, the `parallel=True`+`prange` may be slower on your machine (please test without).

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```py
my_array   =  np.random.rand(p, q, 2)
res_array = np.array([x[1]-x[0] for x in [np.meshgrid(my_array[i,:,0], my_array[i,:,0]) for i in range(p)]], np.float32).reshape(p,q,r)
```

But takes more time than you.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, I tried this but indeed this takes longer.