# Fast alternative to conditionally set an array elements

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have two given 3d arrays `x_dist` and `y_dist` each of shape `(36,50,50)`. Elements in `x_dist` and `y_dist` are of type `np.float32` and can be positive, negative or zero. I need to create a new array `res_array`, where I set its value to `(1-y_dist)*(x_dist)` at all indexes except for where the condition `((x_dist <= 0) | ((x_dist > 0) & (y_dist > (1 + x_dist))))` is `True`. My current implementation is as follows.

```
res_array  = (1-y_dist)*(x_dist)
res_array[((x_dist <= 0) | ((x_dist > 0) & (y_dist > (1 + x_dist))))] = 0.0
```

However, I need to run the code that contains this code snipet thousands of time and I am sure there is a smarter and more faster way to do the same. Can you please help me here to get a performance wise better code or one-liner?

Comment: If you want to keep your vectorized version, you can consider something like `numexpr` instead of `numba`

Comment: "Can you please help me here to get a performance wise better code or one-liner?" You really shouldn't be relating these things in your head. One-liner is not better or faster necessarily.

Comment: You are right about the above comment. Tried ```numexpr``` over the expression - performance decreased.

Comment: Seems like ```numexpr``` can give speed  benefits but only when you have very large arrays

Comment: Then I would try the `numba` approach... but if these are small arrays, this should be very fast to begin with anyway...

Comment: Thanks @Jerome below for posting an answer through using ```Numba```. This was helpful. After testing, however, I am finding that in my case, still  my original implementation gives better performance over large number of code runs. I am deciding to stick with this. Also, because I could locate another bottleneck in my code and fixing that gave me a desired performance.

Answer (score 2):

**Numba JIT** can be used to do that efficiently. Here is an implementation:

```py
@njit
def fastImpl(x_dist, y_dist):
    res_array = np.empty(x_dist.shape)
    for z in range(res_array.shape[0]):
        for y in range(res_array.shape[1]):
            for x in range(res_array.shape[2]):
                xDist = x_dist[z,y,x]
                yDist = y_dist[z,y,x]
                if xDist > 0.0 and yDist <= (1.0 + xDist):
                    res_array[z,y,x] = (1.0 - yDist) * xDist
    return res_array
```

Here are performance results on random input matrices:

```
Original implementation: 494 µs ± 6.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 500 loops each)
New implementation: 37.8 µs ± 236 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 500 loops each)
```

The new implementation is about 13 times faster (without taking into account the compilation/warm-up time).

Comment: I got broadly similar results, but found I can wring a further 10-15% improvement by splitting the `if` statement into 2 tests and only bothering to look up `yDist` if `xDist>0.0`.

Comment: `np.zeros(x_dist.shape)` is nothing more than a `np.empty(x_dist.shape)` combined with a loop to set all values to zero. You can get a further speedup of about 30-40% if you allocate the output with `np.empty` and adding a else `res_array[z,y,x]=0` statement to get the same result.